# Base 64 encoding from command line gives different output than other methods

Tags: shell, base64, command-line-interface, echo

I'm attempting to base 64 encode a string.

I used this shell command:

```bash
echo "teststring" | base64
```

And got this output:

```
dGVzdHN0cmluZwo=
```

But when I use an online tool, the result is:

```
dGVzdHN0cmluZw==
```

Why are they different?

Answer (score 23):

`echo` outputs the string and a newline at the end. If you want just the string you provided, use `echo -n`

Comment: $ echo  | base64  returns `Cg==`

Answer (score 2):

Everyone knows the way to to suppress the newline character is to use `echo -n`. What this answer presupposes is… what if it isn't?

---

The main problem is that the `-n` option is not POSIX-compliant, so is not guaranteed to work in all environments. In fact — unlike other common options such as `-e` — the `-n` option is explicitly called out as being non-compliant in [the POSIX specification for the `echo` utility](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009604599/utilities/echo.html):

> If the first operand is **-n**, or if any of the operands contain a backslash ( '\' ) character, the results are implementation-defined.
>
> On XSI-conformant systems, if the first operand is **-n**, it shall be treated as a string, not an option.

They spend a few lines of the spec trashing `echo`:

> The *echo* utility has not been made obsolescent because of its extremely widespread use in historical applications...
>
> The two different historical versions of *echo* [System V and BSD] vary in fatally incompatible ways.

So what is the solution? Once again, it's in the POSIX specification:

> It is not possible to use *echo* portably across all POSIX systems unless both **-n** (as the first argument) and escape sequences are omitted.
>
> The [*printf*](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009604599/utilities/printf.html) utility can be used portably to emulate any of the traditional behaviors of the *echo* utility...
>
> New applications are encouraged to use [*printf*](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009604599/utilities/printf.html) instead of *echo*.

So the real answer to this question is:

```bash
printf "teststring" | base64
```

Pedantic? Perhaps; and maybe 95% of the time you know your command will be running under GNU Bash. However, it doesn't hurt to script for the remaining 5%.