# Base64 encoding from Node and openssl library produce different output

Tags: node.js, openssl, base64, echo

Why do the following produce different outputs?

1. OpenSSL command line

```sh
echo Chris | openssl base64
# Q2hyaXMK
```

2. Node.js

```
new Buffer('Chris').toString('base64')
// Q2hyaXM=
```

I'm trying to use the `passport-http` library for **Basic authentication**, and it appears to be expecting encoded data in the format of #1. This is a problem for me as all my tests rely on Node for generating encoded data (mocha, supertest).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Base 64 encoding from command line gives different output than other methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17484616/base-64-encoding-from-command-line-gives-different-output-than-other-methods)

Answer (score 7):

The difference is that the **echo** command appends a **newline** character (`\n`) at the end of its output.

In other words, the *Base64 encoding* for `Chris` is indeed `Q2hyaXM=`, **but** the representation of `Chris\n` (where `\n` is just a `newline` character) is `Q2hyaXMK`.

You might want to compare with:

```
new Buffer('Chris\n')
```

... or better yet, we can find in [the `man`ual entry for `echo`](http://linuxcommand.org/lc3_man_pages/echoh.html) that:

> 

```
Options:
  -n    do not append a newline
```

So, simply using:

```bash
echo -n Chris | openssl base64
#    ^^
```

Would output `Q2hyaXM=` as expected!

Comment: The question & answer you wrote are so good to know. So, I translated them to share with Korean developers at [ctrlaltdel](http://ctrlaltdel.co.kr). If you mind it, please let me know and it will be deleted.